# Toggle iCloud sync during runtime

Tags: swift, icloud, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I have a SwiftUI App, where the user can buy with in-app purchases some premium features. One of this features is iCloud sync over more devices. I am using CoreData to save users data.
My persistent container:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "store name")
        let description: NSPersistentStoreDescription? = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
        let remoteChangeKey: String = "NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationOptionKey"
        if(description != nil) {
            description!.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
            description!.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: remoteChangeKey)
        }
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
```

My question is how can I toggle on/off cloud sync when the user buy a subscription. I don't want hat the user have to restart the app.
I also want that the user can toggle this setting in the in-app settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your variable as a `NSPersistentContainer` instead of `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. On launch, if the user has cloud sync, load the cloud kit persistent container, otherwise load the non-cloud kit one.

When the switch is toggled, reload the container, following the same rules. To reload the container, I would add the property to a manager object, in which I would add some methods that reload the the container depending on the user's settings.

Comment: Something like that?
`
lazy var .....
let container = self.iapManager.isPremiumVersion ? NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "store name") : NSPersistentContainer(name: "store name")
....
`
But haw can I reload the container?

Comment: I have been able to find a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355720/coredatacloudkit-on-off-icloud-sync-toggle

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118924?answerId=368354022#368354022) given by an engineer from Apple,
the right way to do this is to set the `cloudKitContainerOptions` to nil when you want to disable iCloud sync. However, simply setting it to nil will not work. A new container needs to be created every time user changes their preference

```swift
class DataController: ObservableObject {

    private var container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer!

    init(iCloudSync: Bool) {
        setupContainer(iCloud: iCloudSync)
    }

    private func setupContainer(iCloud: Bool) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Model_Name")

        guard let description: NSPersistentStoreDescription = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError()
        }

        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)

        if iCloud == false {
            description.cloudKitContainerOptions = nil
        }

        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error {
                print("Failed to load data \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    var iCloudSync: Bool {
        get { container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.cloudKitContainerOptions != nil }
        set { setupContainer(iCloud: newValue) }
    }
}
```

You can either have a singleton of DataController or maintain an object in AppDelegate