# toggle between local and iCloud CoreData store

Tags: swiftui, core-data, icloud

this is my PersistenceController:

```swift
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "LogModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores {(descr, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Container load failed: \(error)")
            }
        }
        
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    }
}
```

here I inject the container.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var persistanceContainer = PersistenceController()

    var body: some Scene {        
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(CoreBluetoothViewModel())
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistanceContainer.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this View to toggle between Cloud and Local store.

```swift
struct iCloudSyncView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State private var cloudEnabled = true

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("iCloud sync", isOn: $cloudEnabled)
    }
}
```

I know that i have to use the `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`for the cloud and the `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`for the local store.

Also I found this article:
[CoreData+CloudKit | On/off iCloud sync toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355720/coredatacloudkit-on-off-icloud-sync-toggle)

But I just can't get it to work :/ 
Can someone please tell me how I have to implement this?

---

I would add it like this:

```swift
struct PersistenceController {
    
    let iCloud = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "iCloud")
    
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    var container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init() {
        if iCloud {
            container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "LogModel")
        } else {
            container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "LogModel")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores {(descr, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Container load failed: \(error)")
            }
        }
        
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to load the new container when toggle is changed.

```swift
Toggle("iCloud sync", isOn: $cloudEnabled)
      .onChange(of: cloudEnabled) { value in
           saveContext()
           UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "iCloud")
           //get new container
      }
```

Comment: What part of that answer doesn't work? I don't see any attempts to implement that solution.

Comment: I added something above

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways

1. add local and cloud configurations to the model editor and set them on the store description and assign different entities to each config.
2. Use affectedStores for fetching and assign(to:) when creating new objects to manually select the store.

1 is best.